# How to prevent screen lock on my application with swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, locking, screen

How can I prevent screen lock only when using Navigation?

Waze has the option to do that, how can I do this in my App?

Answer (score 289, accepted):

Use this:

**Objective-C:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];
```

**Swift (legacy):**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

**Swift 3 and above:**

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

Make sure to import `UIKit`.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623070-isidletimerdisabled) is the link to the documentation from developer.apple.com.

Comment: Swift should be `UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true`

Comment: Swift 3: `UIApplication.shared.idleTimerDisabled = true`

Comment: It changed to ```UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true```

Comment: where to add this line? I don't have AppDelegate.swift as I'm using react-native

Comment: @PradnyanandMilindPohare you can add it wherever you want, just make sure this line it's executed

Answer (score 25):

For Swift 3.0 here are two options depending on where you want to invoke the code:

**Inside AppDelegate.swift:**

`application.idleTimerDisabled = true`

**Outside AppDelegate.swift:**

`UIApplication.shared().isIdleTimerDisabled = true`

Comment: Outside AppDelegate.swift code should be like: `UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false`

Answer (score 17):

Swift 4

in AppDelegate.swift file, add the following line inside **application** function:

```
application.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use my little lib [Insomnia](https://github.com/ochococo/Insomnia) (Swift 3, iOS 9+) - another nice feature is that you can prevent from sleeping only when charging.

The `idleTimerDisabled` soultion is okay but you have to remember to set it to `false` afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

SwiftUI code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Prevent Screen Sleep")
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Disable the idle timer when the view appears
            UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
        }
        .onDisappear {
            // Re-enable the idle timer when the view disappears
            UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more advanced case you can use our small project: [ScreenSleepManager](https://github.com/SparingSoftware/ScreenSleepManager) or if it's just about particular **ViewControllers** - use [Insomnia](https://github.com/ochococo/Insomnia) as pointed earlier. Manual dealing with `idleTimerDisabled` almost always caused me some issues (like forgot to re-set to false or handle multiple (nested) modules trying to set it).