# How to trigger screenlock/pinlock earlier?

Tags: ios, lockscreen

How to bring the screen lock earlier than it's set for? 
I want to do achieve the opposite of this: [How to prevent screen lock on my application with swift on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329185/how-to-prevent-screen-lock-on-my-application-with-swift-on-ios)
So even when it's not a due time for a phone to be locked, the app will trigger the lock screen.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In iOS an external App dont have the rights to trigger the lock screen

Comment: (For fairly obvious reasons; imagine a malicious app that immediately re-locks the screen.)

Comment: @ceejayoz Well, I guess it will never be allowed to the store by Apple review team. But, yeah, I get what you mean