# How do I prevent Interface Controller from locking screen? (WatchOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit

I'm trying to make a specific Interface Controller (on my independent Watch App) [not go idle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623070-isidletimerdisabled).

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329185/how-to-prevent-screen-lock-on-my-application-with-swift-on-ios), but ran into the issue that an independent Watch App cannot support UIKit. I've been trying to find a work-around, but haven't found anything yet.

Here's the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
 UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No watch app, independent or otherwise, can use UIKit.  watchOS apps use WatchKit.

There is no direct equivalent to `isIdleTimerDisabled` due to the more limited battery life of watches.

If your app is a "self care" or "mindfulness" app then you can use an [extended runtime session](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/using_extended_runtime_sessions) to remain as the front most app for 10 minutes or 1 hour.

If it is a fitness app then you can use an [`HKWorkoutSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/running_workout_sessions) to be the default front most app when the user raises their wrist during the workout.